# SQL Server - get first and last (by datetime) DataPoints value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have two tables in SQL Server 2016 database:

**Meters:**

```
    MeterId int [PK]
    Name varchar
```

**DataPoints:**

```
    DataPointId int [PK]
    DateTime datetimeoffset
    Value decimal
    MeterId int [FK -> Meters.MeterId]
```

What I need to do is to read the first and last (oldest and latest) datapoint's DateTime and Value for each Meter - the result table should look like this:

```
Meter Name | First DateTime | First Value | Last DateTime | Last Value
-----------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------
Meter 1    | 2017-04-30...  | 233.55      |  2017-08-30...| 83.5 
Meter 2    | 2017-01-10...  | 11.12       |  2017-01-01...| 55.5
```

I was able to write a query which would read min and max datapoint DateTimes for each Meter, but this query does not contain Value field:

```
select
    Meters.Name as [Meter Name],
    min(DataPoints.DateTime) as [First DateTime],
    max(DataPoints.DateTime) as [Last DateTime]
from Meters
left join DataPoints on DataPoints.MeterId = Meters.MeterId
group by Meters.Name
```

How to modify this query so that First/Last Value fields would also be included in result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have made it this way, by joining DataPoints twice like this:

```
SELECT Meters.Name, 
       t1.Value, 
       t1.DateTime, 
       t2.Value, 
       t2.DateTime
FROM 
    (SELECT DataPoints.MeterId, 
            MIN(DataPoints.DateTime) as FirstDateTime, 
            MAX(DataPoints.DateTime) as LastDateTime
     FROM DataPoints
     GROUP BY DataPoints.MeterId) as SubQuery
INNER JOIN DataPoints t1
    ON t1.DateTime = SubQuery.FirstDateTime AND t1.MeterId = SubQuery.MeterId 
INNER JOIN DataPoints t2
    ON t2.DateTime = SubQuery.LastDateTime AND t2.MeterId = SubQuery.MeterId
right join Meters on Meters.MeterId = DataPoints.MeterId
```

It provides way better performance. `DataPoints` table has indexes created on `DataPointId` and `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
select distinct m.Name as MeterName,
       min(dp.DateTime) over (partition by m.name) as FirstDateTime,
       max(dp.DateTime) over (partition by m.name)  as LastDateTime,
       first_value(value) over (partition by m_name order by dp.datetime) as first_value,
       first_value(value) over (partition by m_name order by dp.datetime desc) as last_value
from dbo.Meters m left join
     dbo.DataPoints dp
     on dp.MeterId = m.MeterId;
```

Unfortunately, `first_value()` (and `last_value()`) are not aggregation functions.  This is one of the rare cases where using `select distinct` for aggregation makes sense.

For performance, you want indexes on `DataPonts(MeterId, datetime, value)`.  I would also rewrite the conditions as:

```
select distinct m.Name as MeterName,
       min(dp.DateTime) over (partition by dp.MeterId) as FirstDateTime,
       max(dp.DateTime) over (partition by dp.MeterId)  as LastDateTime,
       first_value(value) over (partition by dp.MeterId order by dp.datetime) as first_value,
       first_value(value) over (partition by dp.MeterId order by dp.datetime desc) as last_value
from dbo.Meters m left join
     dbo.DataPoints dp
     on dp.MeterId = m.MeterId;
```

I'm pretty sure the `MeterId` and `MeterName` are synonymous.  This will allow the code to use the index.

Another method that might work with the same index is:

```
select m.*, firstdp.*, lastdp.*
from dbo.Meters m outer apply
     (select top (1) dp.datetime, dp.value
      from dbo.DataPoints dp
      where dp.MeterId = m.MeterId
      order by datetime asc
     ) firstdp outer apply
     (select top (1) dp.datetime, dp.value
      from dbo.DataPoints dp
      where dp.MeterId = m.MeterId
      order by datetime desc
     ) lastdp;
```

With the index, I wouldn't be surprised if this were rather zippy.

Comment: @pitersmx . . . Oops.  I left the `last_value()` in by mistake -- that was causing the problem.  Here is a SQL Fiddle on a simplified data set that shows how it works:  That doesn't make sense.  Here is a SQL Fiddle that shows the idea (on a simplified data set):  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/17333.  The `select distinct` is definitely reducing the number of rows..

Comment: However one issue I am facing with this is performance - it is very slow. For Meters table with 50 records and DataPoints table with 400k records this query needs ~36 seconds to complete.